# Как в случае отсутствия значения вывести NULL

Tags: sql

Допустим мне необходимо вывести менеджеров сотрудников, а в случае отсутствия у сотрудника менеджера, вывести `NULL`?

Таблица `EMPLOYEES`
В ней два столбца `employee_name` и `manager_name`

Если написать 
`SELECT employee_name, manager_name FROM EMPLOYEES`

Выведет пустое поле в столбце `manager_name`, если менеджера нет, а нужно вывести `NULL`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` Вам поможет. Если по этим двум словам не понятно - @BOPOH прав: таблицы в студию

Comment: и что? если у сотрудника нет менеджера, следовательно колонка `manager_name` будет пустой... Что надо-то?

Answer (score 1):

После совметсного обсуждения с @BOPOHом предлагается такой вариант:

```
SELECT employee_name, NULLIF(TRIM(manager_name),'') as manager_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Замечание: этот вариант подходит, если нужно выводить именно `NULL`. Если не `NULL`, а что-то другое, то подойдет вот этот:

```
SELECT employee_name, IF(CONCAT(manager_name,'')='', [что-то другое], manager_name) as manager_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Я в таких случаях еще `TRIM()` добавляю на всякий случай: `IF(CONCAT(TRIM(manager_name),'')='', NULL, manager_name)`

Comment: а не проще было бы сделать сразу `nullif(trim(manager_name), '')`?

Comment: @BOPOH проверил: не срабатывает, если сравнивать с `''`. Выдает `NULL` всегда.

Comment: что именно не срабатывает? `nullif(exp1, exp2)` вернет null если exp1 = exp2, в противном случае вернет exp1, т.е. `nullif(trim(manager_name), '')` вернет null только тогда, когда trim(manager_name) = '' или когда trim(manager_name) = null.

Comment: Вот, прогнал через одну из своих баз:
`nullif(trim(`unitEn`),'')  unitEn  //
-------------------------  -------- //
(NULL)                     (NULL)  //
(NULL)                             //
lb                         lb     ` . Если `unitEn =NULL` - ответ `NULL`; если `unitEn='`' - ответ `NULL`; если `unitEn = 'lb`' - ответ `'lb'`

Comment: ну так же и должно работать? или я что-то путаю?

Comment: а, ну да :):):):)... Упс... поставьте свой вариант как ответ - я свой уберу